# How to define pom properties in gradle project?

Tags: maven, gradle

I can not resolve the dependency once has variables, like ${qualifier}.

Some irregular project in our company such as pom.xml:
[image]

He defined an properties:${qualifier}

In maven project we just need to define properties:
[image]
In Gradle project, I try to:
gradle.properies

```
qualifier = RELEASE
```

build.gradle

```
build.gradle
```

All of above did not works on.

Comment: I can not resolve the dependency for the ${qualifier} in pom.xml. My solution is replacing all the ${qualifier} to `RELEASE` in my local gradle cache repository.

Comment: The produced pom file must have resolved all the version information that does mean not using properties within version tags otherwise no one will be able to consume such poms. Furthermore the question is why this qualifier is needed and for what purpose?

Comment: @khmarbaise  This qualifier for different profile resolve different version dependency.In maven project different profile defined own ${qualifier}.

Comment: Why different profiles? Why resolving different dependencies?  A version is a version nothing else.

Comment: @khmarbaise In our company, we has profie such as dev,test,prod for different env the corresponding ${qualifier} for  SNAPSHOT, RC, RELEASE. Some vulnerable dependencis can be override like SNAPSHOT and RC. A some dependency has three type qualifieies.Using which dependency depend on maven build command.